# jQuery toggleClass only toggles once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which i am trying to toggle its class from one to another. I am able to toggle it only once but it will not return to the original class. I looked around for possible answers and looked into the propogation function, however i am unsure this is the correct use?

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapBreather">
        <div id="counter" class="cInact">
         <!--<canvas id="timerAnimation"></canvas>-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id="startStopCount" class="HomeButton" >Start</button>
    <script>
      $(startStopCount).click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          $('.cInact').toggleClass('cDown cInact');
      });
      $('html').click(function () {
          $('#counter').removeClass('cDown');
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `$('#startStopCount')` typo.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the element via `$('.cInact')`. However, when you toggle the class `.cInact`, you can no longer get that element by `$('.cInact')` (it doesn't have that class anymore).

You can either do a selection with `$('#counter')` (getting the ID instead of the class, because you aren't toggling the ID) or assign the element reference to a variable:

```
var myAwesomeCounter = $('.cInact');

// Then use
myAwesomeCounter.toggleClass('cDown cInact');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're selecting the class 'cInact' and then toggling it's class.
i.e- removing it.

Wen you're trying to select the element again with the same selector: `classname == cInact` it's no longer true for that element. so you select nothing, and nothing happens.

To fix this, try using a different selector- e.g- id, like so-

```
$('#counter').toggleClass('cDown cInact');
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector  $(startStopCount) is wrong. It should be `$("#startStopCount")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $('#startStopCount').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      
    $('.cInact').toggleClass('cDown');
      });

$('html').click(function () {
 $('#counter').removeClass('cDown');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div id="wrapBreather">
     <div id="counter" class="cInact">
     <!--<canvas id="timerAnimation"></canvas>-->
     </div>

        </div>
        <br />
        <button id="startStopCount" class="HomeButton" >Start</button>

      
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#startStopCount').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#counter').toggleClass('cDown cInact');
  });
  $('html').click(function () {
      $('#counter').removeClass('cDown');
  });
```

Better perhaps:

```
  $('#startStopCount').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#counter').toggleClass('cDown cInact');
  });
  $('body').click(function () {
      $('#counter').removeClass('cDown');
  });
```